# Using the Twitter REST API to get tweets within a bounding box

Tags: api, rest, twitter, location, bounding-box

I'm trying to use the Twitter API to get tweets within a bounding box.
Currently, I've managed to do this only with the streaming API, but the tweets flow in rather slow so I am looking to use past tweets.

I can't seem to find a way to do this with the REST API. It seems to allow for 'locations', but how would I do that when my query may fall over several locations or only in partial locations?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to gather tweets in the exact same area using the REST API as I did using the Streaming API.

Comment: In [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) there is the parameter `geocode` with works like a "bounding circle". I haven't used it though. Note that when using REST API you get rate limits. Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess this is the closest thing!